# Java method call using dojo

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, dojo

I have a java class which contains a method, having some business logic in it. I need to call this java method directly from a JSP (except through servelet or struts action or scriplets) on a button click. I know this can be done using DWR (as per its behavior), but are there any possibilities to call java methods directly using dojo framework?

I am concern about dojo instead of using DWR because in my application I'm already using the dojo framework. My app contains struts2 as well but without calling a struts action, using dojo (ajax calls) itself I need to call that particular java method directly as in DWR.

People who have experience in using dojo please guide me on this.

**Note:** Please let me know if you require code parts of my app, but I think above description might be fine enough to understand my motive.

*Thanks.*

Comment: What about a rest call?

Comment: What is wrong with ajax call?

Comment: If you use Struts2, no matter which client-side library / framework you uses, you should call an Action. If you want to call a static method from an utility class, you can wrap it in an action method; if this operation is common to a lot of pages, you can put it in a BaseAction extended by the other ones... just don't use the old dojo integrated with struts2: latest plain dojo, plain jquery, or struts2-jquery

Answer (score 0):

zulox,

What you need to do is set up a [Model-View-Controller architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) with your web application. With this, you can then invoke a method in your back-end code upon a click that has occured in your front end.

With MVC, the view effectively provides the user interface element of the application. It'll render data from the model into a form that is suitable for the user interface.

The controller receives user input and makes calls to model objects and the view to perform appropriate actions.

The model manages fundamental behaviors and data of the application.

**You JSP will look like the following:**

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
           <title>JSP Page</title>
       </head>
    <body>
       <form action="add" method="post">
           Value 1:<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/><br>
           Value 2:<input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
        </form>
    <%String sum="";
     sum = (String)request.getAttribute("val3"); %>
    <input type="text" value="<%=sum%>" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**And then your java file in your back-end will look like the following:**

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 public class add extends HttpServlet {
String val3;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String val1=request.getParameter("val1");
    String val2=request.getParameter("val2");
    if(val1 != null && val2 != null)
    val3=""+(Integer.parseInt(val1)+Integer.parseInt(val2));
    else
    val3="";
    request.setAttribute("val3",val3);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response); 

    try {
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

You're also going to need a web server/servlet container that can host your back end files and serve your JSP's. [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a great one to start learning on. [Here](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheTomcat/article.html) are really great tutorials for Tomcat which will help you get started setting everything up so that you can easily serve pages.

Please let me know if you have any questions!